# Benefit of authentication with a gateway

Tags: authentication, web-service, http-proxy, security-theater

## Given...

- a public web service with enabled SSL/TLS
- the web service enforces authentication using JSON Web Tokens
- a client on a LAN without an Internet connection
- a proxy on the LAN that grants point-to-point connections to mentioned web service

## When.

- I want to connect to the proxy in order to access the web services
- and I discuss with security folks what I have in mind

## Then...

- Security folks (experts/consultants) usually recommend additional authentication with the local proxy
- I think of possible threat scenarios
- I think the recommendation must be copied from some generic security guideline
- I don't see a huge security benefit as authentication is already present but happens at the end of the tunnel

## My reflections so far:

- Even when I do not see huge benefits, an additional layer increases security
- Then: more complex solutions are more error-prone. Errors may decrease security
- A hypothetical attack to the web service (think of DoS) from the LAN would look as if it originates from the proxy and maybe it cannot be linked to a client IP.

But maybe I have missed something. So that's why I ask for a different angle to look at this matter. Maybe someone can point me in the right direction and could show me a risk that absolutely mandates to enable authentication on the proxy. Thanks in advance!